# Autodesk Forge Data Management API. Too many requests on search

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

We use Forge Data Management API to access project documents.
We execute next set of requests:

- **project/v1/hubs** to get hubs (*hubId*)
- **project/v1/hubs/:hubId/projects** to get projects (*projectId* and *rootFolder*)
- **data/v1/projects/:projectId/folders/:folderId/search?filter[fileType]=rvt,nwc,nwd** to get files filtered by extension

On **search** we often get Too Many Requests status code.
We have about 20 files in the project.
Sometimes this request is processed instantly, sometimes 8 seconds, sometimes 20 seconds.

Response body:

```
{"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},"errors":[{"id":"GUID","status":"429","detail":"Too Many Requests"}]}
```

On [this page](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/rate-limiting/dm-rate-limits/) we can see that there is a limit 300 requests/minute. But we get Too Many Requests status after exceeding not more that 10 requests/minute.

Also [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/rate-limiting/forge-rate-limits/) we see that response must contain Retry-after header. But the is no such header.

So i have next questions:

- What is the best practice to search project files by the file extension?
- Why we get Too Many Requests even if we don't exceed the limit?
- What should we do for not getting Too Many Requests status?
- Why the is no Retry-after header in the Too Many Requests response?

Comment: I am afraid you hit an known issue of Search API.I just got to know 429 comes from the underlying system of Search API is not based on how many times a specific Forge App called the endpoint. We apologize for this confusing. I am checking further with team if there is any further information/plan about this issue.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang thanks for the reply. As i understand, the best solution is using GET folders/id/content to get rid of this error and get actual list of files. Correct me if im wrong.